# How to recover the app settings in NSUserDefaults from a dictionary returned by -dictionaryRepresentation?

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults

I'm getting a dictionary representation of the current settings in NSUserDefaults, as NSDictionary.

That was pretty easy using the -dictionaryRepresentation method. However, I need to write that back again. I couldn't find a method to do that easily. Maybe it's just too hot in my office?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `dictionaryRepresentation`.

What you want to do is access your keys directly, and re-set them when they're modified:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
id obj = [defaults objectForKey:@"<key>"];
// MODIFY OBJ
[defaults setObject:obj forKey:@"<key>"];
```

Comment: It's pretty simple as it is, if you ask me.

Comment: Well, I made a deep copy. Was by far simpler ;) But thanks anyways, it's also a solution that works for a small set of settings. Otherwise you would code yourself crazy.